# Symfony 5.4 with Kafka

Tags: symfony, apache-kafka, symfony5, symfony-messenger, symfony5.4

I have a symfony 5.4 project and I want to implement kafka with the symfony messenger component.

I've seen several ways to do this, including this post: [Symfony Messenger with Apache Kafka as queue transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317692/symfony-messenger-with-apache-kafka-as-queue-transport) which implements 4 bundles (all essential?), a bundle https://github.com/KonstantinCodes/messenger-kafka, I'm not sure what best practice to implement.
In the official Symfony documentation, I only found this line:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages
If you have any feedback, I'd love to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what's available on the symfony/messenger documentation:

> If you want to use a transport that's not supported, check out the Enqueue's transport, which supports things like Kafka and Google Pub/Sub.

source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages

So yes, you need all those dependencies.

What happens is that you configure symfony/messenger to use the enqueue driver, which in terms uses kafka.